# UICollectionViewCell reuse issue

Tags: ios, uiview, uicollectionview, calayer, reuseidentifier

I have a storyboard and one of my viewControllers has a CollectionView. I have a prototype cell that has a label inside. I created a class for that prototype cell in order to have access to the label via an IBOutlet property.

The problem is that I have many cells. Inside the `initWithCoder` constructor of the cell I add some `cornerRadius`.

When I push this viewController on the screen, it lags a lot. Without the corner radius it doesn't. I also noticed that `initWithCoder` gets called all the time, for each cell.

I tried to register the cell like this `[self.myCollectionView registerClass:[MyCell class] forReuseIdentifier:@"MyReuseIdentifier"]` but it doesn't work. I dont know how to use the `registerNib` method.

The reuse identifier is set in the storyboard prototype cell.

I don't know how to achieve the rounded corner effect without loss in perforrmance.

Answer (score 0):

I have done my cell corner round in `cellForItemAtIndexPath` method like

```
    cell.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
    cell.imageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

and dont forget to import `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`

Comment: Nope. Doesn't work. I still think it's a problem of reusability.